# Strange results for the error of numerical integration: The Newton-Cotes rules

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximate-integration, truncation-error

I was using the Maple software for the computation of the numerical integration error.
I'm obtaining two strange properties which I'm unable to explain. First for items $(72)$
and $(73)$ below while integrating those natural polynomials as displayed from $0$ to $3\cdot h$ and $5\cdot h$ resp. I'm getting the **exact** coefficient of error in the Simpson's rule and the $6-$Newton-Cotes rule, together with the right order of $h$: $5$ and $7$ resp. Is this a mere coincidence that these two coefficients are the same as they should be ? How could I explain this phenomena ? Next bizarre thing is that this doesn't work for $n$ even, I'm getting just zero: $0$. How should I **fix** the polynomial in $(74)$ with the upper bound to obtain $-\frac{8}{945}h^7$ as given in the second snippet below in the same manner as for $(72)$ and $(73)$ ??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is addressed in the last two sequences of the cited text. In your last example the number of points is odd, the product of the linear factors is an odd function about the middle point of the interval, so the integral is zero.

More in detail, the integral itself is invariant under direction change, so for the most simple case of 3 points and the model case $a,a+h,a+2h=b$ one gets
$$
\int_{-h}^hf(x)dx=\int_{-h}^h [p_3(x)+r(x)(x+h)x(x-h)]dx
\\
=\int_{-h}^h p_3(x)dx +\int_0^h [r(x)-r(-x)](x+h)x(x-h)dx
$$
with $r(x)=f[x,-h,0,h]$ an iterated divided difference, so that $r(x)-r(-x)=2xf[x,-x,-h,0,h]=2x\tilde r(x)$ with $\tilde r(x)=f[x,-x,-h,0,h]=\frac1{4!}f^{(4)}(\xi_x)$, $\xi_x\in(-h,h)$.

Inserting this then gives the remainder term as
$$
2\int_0^h \tilde r(x)(x+h)x^2(x-h)dx=2\tilde r(c)\int_0^h(x^4-h^2x^2)dx
=\frac{2f^{(4)}(\xi_c)}{4!}(\tfrac15-\tfrac13)h^5
$$

So in summary, for odd numbers of points the middle factor gets squared in the computation of the coefficient of the error term.

Comment: Please, how have you obtained that $r(x)$ is exactly that divided difference, why have you chosen that it should be such a one and what is $p_3(x)$ ?

Comment: Interpolation in 4 points is exact in these points. Let these points be $-h,0,h,x$ and evaluate at $x$. Then $$f(x)=p_4(x)=\underbrace{f(-h)+f[-h,0](x+h)+f[-h,0,h](x+h)x}_{=p_3(x)}+\underbrace{f[-h,0,h,x]}_{=r(x)}(x+h)x(x-h).$$ The notation might be special, as the index is the number of points and not the degree as is usual.

Comment: Right, I'm now about to finish my understanding of your answer. Where has disappeared the bar from $r(x)$: in your last equation it is first $$\bar{r}(x)$$ inside the integral and then  $r(c)$ without the bar in front of it.

Comment: $\tilde r$ is a step further from that. It only applies to integration, $\int_{-h}^h f(x)dx=\int_{-h}^hf(-x)dx$ not interpolation. Or you could make it about the interpolation of the even part of $f$, as $f(x)+f(-x)=p_3(x)+p_3(-x)+(r(x)-r(-x))(x+h)x(x-h)$ and the odd part of $r$ has a root at $0$, so one can split off an additional linear factor $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by the **even** part of $f$, what is your definition of this ?

Comment: The even and odd parts of a function f about the origin are $0.5 (f(x)+f(-x))$ and $0.5(f(x)-f(-x))$. So for the exponential these are cosh and sinh, for a polynomial these are the partial polynomials of the even and odd degree terms.

Comment: Please, what is the difference between $c$ and $\xi_c$ in your formula $$2\tilde r(c)\int_0^h(x^4-h^2x^2)dx
=\frac{2f^{(4)}(\xi_c)}{4!}(\tfrac15-\tfrac13)h^5
$$
?

Comment: You get a midpoint $c$ from the integral mean value theorem, and a midpoint $\xi_c$ from reducing the divided difference $f[c,-c,h,0,-h]$ to a 4t derivative.